# How to scroll to the very end/start of screen horizontally with padding?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want my card to disappear in to the phone at the extreme. How would I do this?

Comment: It's useful if you post a minimal example of your layout code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` has padding by default, you can remove it with`EdgeInsets.zero`

```
ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
...
)
```